# Echo a Username via the ID of a user who isnt the Auth:: user in laravel

Tags: laravel

I know that you can echo a Auth User's name via

```
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
```

How can i echo a full list of all other users that are registered in the database??

Been trying for days to figure this out and i am struggling..

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what do you mean by echo a full list? aren't you able to query to db? or you mean all online users?

Comment: Just query all the users in the db (.i.e. `User::all()`) and echo them in a view?

Answer (score 1):

there are many roads to get to Roam.

1: you can do this in your controller (loop throw all model columns):

```
$userNames = User::all();
return view('view')->with('userNames',$userNames);
```

and in your view :

```
@foreach($userNames as $name)
    {{ $name->name }}
$endforeach
```

2: this is also a way to do it using `::pluk` :

```
   $userNames = User::pluck('name');
   return view('view')->with('userNames',$userNames);
```

in your view :

```
    @foreach($userNames as $name)
{{ $name }}
$endforeach
```

to sum up : the first way is used if you want to get data from more than 1 column second way is if you want to get data just from 1 column.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way
In controller

```
$userNames = User::pluck('name');
return view('your-view', compact('userNames'));
```

in view

```
@foreach($userNames as $name)
    {{ $name }}
$endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

So the `User` model is what `Auth::user()` retrieves for the current user.

You can imagine it as an equivalent to `\App\User::findOrFail($user_id);`

To get all users you can do `\App\User::get();`.

If you want to loop and echo out the names of all these users you could do something like:

```
$Users = \App\User::get();
foreach ($Users as $User) {
    echo $User->name;
}
```